# How to read data from a webpage (on different domain) in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web, asp.net-web-api

I have created an online dictionary which takes word in url and displays its meaning on web.
The url is something like this (I am not sharing the actual one):

```
http://some_domain/some_file.php?word=regret&search=Submit
```

The meaning of the word regret is displayed on webpage, I am simply using echo to print results (ex. `echo Meaning[$word]`).

I want to read these results from my other webpages but cannot figure out how to do it. Two things I want to know:

- can I read the results as I have mentioned above
- or I need to make some changes in my `some_file.php` so that the results become readable?

Comment: Learn about CORS or JSONP.

Comment: Or have your server communicate with the other page (you page asks your server to get information form another page and your server gets it then sends it to your page).

Comment: actually i am working on a chrome extension and i am injecting a javascript in webpages opened in chrome and i need to get those results by the injected javascript files , is there any way to do so

Comment: @SLaks CORS/JSONP have security issues. You're better off setting sane `Allow-Origin` headers. For small applications, you might even have a server do the `fetch`es and pass the result to the client.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format lists and inline code so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit question to provide any code samples and additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!